# Why does the Webdriver connects to "http://localhost:5555/" instead of "about:blank"?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Sorry for asking this basic question. I am still wondering why does the webdriver connects to `http://localhost:5555/"` instead of `about:blank` when `IE` is launched. Is there any particular reason behind it? Any answers will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: To use `IE webdriver` you should start `IEDriverServer` on your local machine. `5555` is default port for the server. I guess this is the reason :) You can search for appropriate `DesiredCapabilities` to change default homepage

Comment: @Andersson - Alright! thank you. Appreciate your quick response..:)

Comment: @Andersson I think you need to post it as an answer, and OP has to accept it..:)

Comment: @SaurabhGaur, I'm not sure that this is the best answer for the question, so I let someone else to provide extended answer :)